# Calculating mode with modeest package in R

Tags: r

I am using the below code for calculating the mode of a dataframe:

```
library(modeest)
apply(df[ ,2:length(df)], 1, mfv)
```

My data looks like this:

```
Item    A   B   C
Book001 56  32  56
Book002 95  95  20
Book003 50  89  50
Book004 6   65  40
```

It gives me the following output:

```
[[1]]
[1] 56

[[2]]
[1] 95

[[3]]
[1] 50

[[4]]
[1]  6 40 65
```

This code is perfect only if the data contains a recurring term. 
How can I display the mode as `NA` when there is no recurring term?

Comment: `apply(df[ ,2:length(df)], 1, mfv)` can be replaced by `apply(df[-1], 1, mfv)` for conciseness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try with a custom function:

```
foo <- function(x){
  out <- mfv(x)
  if(length(out) > 1)  out <- NA
  return(out)
}
apply(df[ ,2:length(df)], 1, foo)
# [1] 56 95 50 NA
```